# Set a custom name to a facebook tab page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've tried in this way but in the tab I found the 
same name of my application

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '/tabs', 'post', {
      access_token: token,
      app_id: BT.fbAppId,
      custom_name:'mycoolname'
    }, function(response){
        if(response===true){

        }
        else{
          alert('Error on insert tab');
        }
});
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I realized reading better the doc that you have to update after the insert like:

```
FB.api('/' + data.page_id + '/tabs/app_'+BT.fbAppId, 'post', {
  access_token: data.token,
  custom_name:BT.current.title
  }, function(response){
    if(response===true){
    }
    else{
      alert('Error on update tab');
    }
});
```